# Write S in set notation when...

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$V = ℝ^4$, $S$ is the set of all vectors $(x_1, 0, x_3, 2)$ and determine if $S$ is a vector subspace of $V$.

I'm somewhat new to vector subspaces and having a little trouble with this problem. As for the set notation I have:
$$S=\{{(x_1, 0, x_3, 2):x_1,x_3 \in \Bbb R\}}$$
I was wondering if that is the correct way to represent the conditions above in set notation. If so, how would we proceed to check if $S$ is a vector subspace of $V$. All the examples I have found doing such are of the form $S = \{x\in \Bbb R : x = (2k, -3k), k \in \Bbb R\}$ or something similar. I am not really sure how to do it using the set notation form I came up with. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the sum of two such elements in $S$? Is a scalar multiple of such an element in $S$? Is the null vector in $S$?

Comment: @Bernard I don't know how I would verify that given my set notation. I know how I would check for closure under addition and scalar multiplication on the example form (that i provided above) but not for the set notation I came up with. Unless, my set notation is itself incorrect and should instead resemble something closer to the example form?

Comment: Your set notation is perfectly correct and is not fundamentally different the example you provided.  You just have to ask yourself the questions I recalled, and answer yes or no.  If you can answer ‘yes’ to all, it is a subspace. If you can answer ‘no’ to any of the questions, it is not.

Comment: okay so if my set notation is correct then we would have to check for closure under addition and scalar multiplication and for the null vector to confirm it is a subspace. (as you stated above) To check for closure under addition would it be something akin to let $q = (x_1, 0, x_3, 2)$ and $r = (y_1, 0, x_3, 2)$. Then check that q + r = something that is in S?  I guess what I am confused on is how to necessarily check for closure without some sort of given equation. Using what i described above I came to $q+r=(x_1y_1, 0, x_3y_3, 4) \notin S$. Meaning it is not a subspace.

Comment: That' right. You do have implicit equations: $x_2=0$, $x_4=2$. Actually, $S$ is an *affine* subspace (i. e. a vector space translated by a vector).

Comment: @Bernard Wait so you are saying I did it correctly but $S$ is in fact a vector subspace? Or am I misunderstanding? If this is the case then how can it be a subspace? My understanding is that since $x_4 \ne 2$ it cannot be a subspace.

Comment: No it is a vector space *translated* by some vector. Just think of plane geometry: proper subspaces are the origin and lines through the origin. Affine lines  are lines not necessarily through the origin (and parallel to exactly one such line, called its direction).

Comment: @Bernard I'm sorry but I'm not understanding what you mean when you say think of $.

Comment: My editing process bugged… I've completed my comment.

Comment: oh okay. I see, thank you very much for your explanation.